# replace '?' with '/' via htaccess in url

Tags: .htaccess

I have an url which I have created with htaccess rule:

http://domain.com/foldername/name-in-location

This is working fine, when on this url and click on page 2, it becomes

http://domain.com/foldername/name-in-location?page=2

I want `name-in-location?page=2` to be replaced with `name-in-location/page-2`

My current `.htaccess` looks like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+foldername/([^&]+)?page=([^&]+) 
RewriteRule ^ /JustFind/([^&]+)/%1? [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d –
```

Comment: What does you current htaccess file look like? What have you tried?

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+foldername/([^&]+)?page=([^&]+)              
RewriteRule ^ /JustFind/([^&]+)/%1? [L,R=301]                                    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d